# allow computer to access files on the phone from the computer

Tags: android, ubuntu

I want to access my phone data from the computer and for this I have to allow the computer to do it from the phone.
The problem is that the phone's screen doesn't work, so is there any way to allow the computer to access the phone's data from my computer?

Oh, and if it matters, I'm using ubuntu and android....

Answer (score 2):

You can use adb if the phone has USB debugging turned on.  adb is a program that allows you to access a connected android device.  just use `adb shell` to get an interactive shell on the device, or `adb shell command` to run a command.  To push files to the device use `adb push`, and to pull them from the device use `adb pull`

Comment: thanks for the quick answer!
I tried, but it says that the device is unauthorized...

Comment: You need to authorize it on the device first, it will pop up a screen when plugged in if USB debugging is on.  If it isn't on, turn it on

Comment: I know, but as I said in the question, my phone's screen doesn't work so I need a different way to do it

Comment: Then its not possible.  Any way to do it requires you to connect to the device, which for security reasons requires to approve on device.